# Overlay images code need some for loop in python

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am working with the below code which is lengthy is there a to make the code clean and short using some for loop.

```
from PIL import Image
#1
bg = Image.open("bg1.png")
w = Image.open("w1.png")
bg.paste(w, (0,0), w)
#2
body = bg
body1 = Image.open("body.png")
body.paste(body1, (0,0), body1)
#3
eye = bg
eye1 = Image.open("eye1.png")
eye.paste(eye1, (0,0), eye1)
#4
eb = eye
eb1 = Image.open("eb1.png")
eb.paste(eb1, (0,0), eb1)
#5
mouth = eb
mouth1 = Image.open("mouth1.png")
mouth.paste(mouth1, (0,0), mouth1)
#6
nose = mouth
nose1 = Image.open("nose1.png")
nose.paste(nose1, (0,0), nose1)
#7
hair = nose
hair1 = Image.open("h1.png")
hair.paste(hair1, (0,0), hair1)
#8
dress = hair
dress1 = Image.open("d2.png")
dress.paste(dress1, (0,0), dress1)


dress.show()
```

New to python as newbie

Thank you in adavance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would define a function to paste one image on top of another:

```
def layer_image(image, file_to_paste):
    to_paste = Image.open(file_to_paste)
    return image.paste(to_paste, (0,0), to_paste)
```

Then you can loop through your list of images:

```
files = ["bg1.png", "w1.png", "body.png", "eye1.png", "mouth1.png", "nose1.png", "h1.png", "d2.png"]

start_image = files.pop(0)
img = Image.open(start_image)

for file in files:
    img = layer_image(img, file)
```